# WKWebView and Instagram embed

Tags: ios, unicode, instagram-api, wkwebview

I found a very interesting problem in WKWebview and rendering of instagram embeds in iOS 8. If the HTML contains a unicode character such as  – (U+2013), the WKWebView executes the oEmbed API calls but gets Chinese characters in response. Please see the screenshot that is taken from Safari web inspector. The javascript code is unable to display the embed in this case. If I take off the unicode character –, the instagram embed gets displayed fine.

The problem with unicode characters does not occur in WKWebview is specific to iOS8, does not happen in iOS 9.  Anyone else seen an issue like this? Any feedback will be highly appreciated.

[image]